# Writing a function in Postgresql 8.2

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function in Postgres 8.2 that will analyze 4 specific columns out of a data set we use for reporting purposes and then return text that categorizes the record with specific text.

In our old reporting environment, I would leverage the reporting tool (Crystal Reports) to calculate this but the directive I have received is that it should be done as a function in the database.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do (please excuse the errors, I am still learning the basics)

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnc_Breakdown(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying)  
RETURNS character varying AS $$
DECLARE
breakdown character varying; 
BEGIN
IF $1 in ('ABCD') THEN breakdown:= "CSS"
ELSE
IF $1 like ('DCA%) AND $2 IN ('District 123','District 124') and $3 IN ('
THEN breakdown:= "FAB"
ELSE breakdown:= "OTHERS"
END IF;
RETURN breakdown;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Besides not really telling us what your question is, you don't include valid syntax (it looks like you forgot a closing apostrophe after `'DCA%`, and `$3 IN ('` seems to be missing some code). Please fix and resubmit as a question with source code that at least compiles. Also note that you are using a version of PostgreSQL which has been out of support since 2011: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ You should be scheduling an upgrade as soon as practicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function need some formatting and semicolons, but in general it's fine. I'd also suggest some friendly formatting, rememeber that you're writing code for people not for computer:

```
create or replace function fnc_Breakdown
(
  character varying,
  character varying,
  character varying,
  character varying
)
returns character varying as $$
declare
  breakdown character varying; 
begin
  if $1 = 'ABCD' then
    breakdown := 'CSS';
  elseif $1 like 'DCA%' and $2 in ('District 123','District 124') then
    breakdown:= 'FAB';
  else
    breakdown:= 'OTHERS';
  end if;
  return breakdown;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable;
```

Actually such a simple task could be made without function at all, just with case expression:

```
case
    when a = 'ABCD' then
        'CSS'
    when a like 'DCA%' and b in ('District 123','District 124') then
        'FAB'
    else
        'OTHERS'
end
```

see [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/473e8/3) to fiddle around with queries